# Writing a personal narrative and wondering if this application of present tense mixes with most of the sentence, which is in past tense

Tags: sentence, past-tense, present-tense

This sentence doesn't sound all that right, but at the same time I think it is.

> I grabbed underwear, a tee with red sleeves and khaki shorts and
>   headed for the master bathroom, **which houses the only tub I want to
>   take a shower in**, which I then did after locking the door and
>   grabbing soap.

The event I'm writing about was literally last week, and because of that all of my habits apparent in the writing still stick with me. Is that [the bold words] the proper application of present tense within past tense?

Comment: It may be ***true*** that the tub is still in that bathroom, and that it's still the only one you want to use (at time of writing), but if that's not ***relevant*** there's no good reason to switch from Past to Present tense for your (comma-delineated) parenthetical clause.  Syntactically it's perfectly valid either way though, so this is essentially "writing advice".

Comment: Ask on writers.SE?